# $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(5+n)^{2n-1}((n+1)^{{1}/{n}}-n^{{1}/{n}})$ using $e$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need some help with the following expression:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(5+n)^{2n-1}((n+1)^{{1}/{n}}-n^{{1}/{n}}).$$

What I have done so far is the following:

\begin{align*}
(5+n)^{2n-1} ((n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}-n^{\frac{1}{n}})&= (1+\frac{5}{n})^{2n-1} \cdot n^{2n-1} \cdot ((1+\frac{1}{n})^\frac{1}{n}-1)^n \cdot n\\
&= (1+\frac{5}{n})^{2n-1} \cdot n^{2n} \cdot ((1+\frac{1}{n})^\frac{1}{n}-1)^n
\end{align*}

Now I would like to use that $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n = e^x $ but i dont know exactly how to use it in this case.

Comment: The second factor is of the form $A-B$ where both $A, B$ tend to $1$ and hence both $A, B$ can be replaced by their logarithms.

Answer (score 1):

We can use it for an asymptotic analysis to guess what the limit is, indeed

$$(5+n)^{2n-1} = n^{2n-1}\left(1+\frac 5{n}\right)^{2n-1}=n^{2n-1}\left[\left(1+\frac 5{n}\right)^{n}\right]^\frac{2n-1}{n}\sim e^{10}n^{2n-1}$$

and since

$$(n+1)^{{1}/{n}}=e^{\frac{\log (n+1)}{n}} \sim 1+\frac{\log(n+1)}n$$

$$n^{{1}/{n}}=e^{\frac{\log n}{n}} \sim 1+\frac{\log n}n$$

we have

$$((n+1)^{{1}/{n}}-n^{{1}/{n}})\sim \frac{\log(n+1)}n-\frac{\log n}n=\frac1n \log \frac{n+1}{n}=\frac1{n^2}\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$

therefore

$$(5+n)^{2n-1}((n+1)^{{1}/{n}}-n^{{1}/{n}}) \sim \frac{e^{10}n^{2n-1}\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}{n^2} \to \infty$$

Comment: The original question I wanted to ask is nearly the same i.e. the Same limit just that ((n+1)^1/n-n^1/n)^n * (n+5)^(2n-1)

Comment: Unfortunaly i am at my phone right now, i want to say that the last bracket has power to n

Comment: @Gaus123 You can raise another question for that if you can't get an answer. Bye